# Ошибка MemoryError при работе с большим кличеством файлов

Tags: python

У меня есть текстовые файлы, состоящие из словарей, количеством 10000-20000. Я преобразую файл в список из словарей, для того чтобы работать с ним в дальнейшем.

```
book = list(map(lambda line: json.loads(line), open('1.001.txt')))
```

Таких файлов 2500. Мне нужно получить информацию по всем из них, например выудить один элемент из последнего словаря каждого файла и составить список этих элементов в количестве равном числу этих файлов.

Я попробовал сделать все через простой цикл:

```
books = []
for text in glob.iglob('data\*'):
    book = list(map(lambda line: json.loads(line), open(text)))
    books.append(book)
```

И наткнулся на ошибку Memory Error и соответственно, загрузку оперативки. Видимо, этот подход не правильный. Каким методом надо работать? Время выполнения программы не критично, мне это нужно лишь один раз.

Comment: Зависит от того, чито конкретно вы хотите сделать, слово "работать" слишком абстрактно

Comment: Так обрабатывайте по частям, освобождая память. В примере Вы создаёте список из словарей в количестве 25.000.000-50.000.000 штук (а в них ещё элементы есть...). При этом Вам всего лишь нужен _"один элемент из последнего словаря каждого файла"_. Так возьмите этот элемент из словаря, удалите словарь (или это может сделать сборщик мусора) и обрабатывайте следующий.

Comment: если вы приведете небольшие примеры входных данных и того, что хотите получить на выходе, то вероятность получения адекватных ответов многократно возрастет ;)